# VB6 Formatting a string Problem

Tags: vb6, formatting, string-formatting

My question is simple..
How do I convert a string like `"445B986D2DD3B41852964ABA11408E82"` to `445B9-86D2D-D3B41-85296-4ABA1-1408E82`
It should be in the format `'#####-#####-#####-#####-#####-############`(the last matter does not matter)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method using `MOD`

```
Dim OldStr As String
OldStr = "445B986D2DD3B41852964ABA11408E82"
Dim NewStr As String
For i = 1 To Len(OldStr)
    NewStr = NewStr & Mid(OldStr, i, 1)
    If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
        NewStr = NewStr & "-"
    End If
Next
```

and using `STEP`

```
For i = 1 To Len(st) Step 5
    ss = ss & Mid(st, i, 5) & "-"
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just add the dashes:

```
s = Left(s, 5) + "-" + Mid(s, 6, 5) + "-" + Mid(s, 11, 5) + "-" + Mid(s, 16, 5) _  
               + "-" + Mid(s, 21, 5) + "-" + Right(s, Len(s) - 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Mid(), Left(), Right() functions and concatenate operator (&). E.g:

```
dim str
str = "12345678"
str = Left(str, 2) &"-"& Mid(str, 2, 2) & "-"& Mid(str, 4, 2) & "-"&Right(str, 2)
MsgBox str ' the output will be 12-34-56-78
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a maskedinput textbox with that mask, but the maxlenght is 64, or i can send a supertextbox made by me with a lot of improvements